# LibreOffice Online on Debian with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, libreoffice, docker-image

I'm trying to install libreoffice online on debian (i can change OS if necessary but still linux) with docker and i tried this image that i found on docker hub :

https://hub.docker.com/r/libreoffice/online/

`docker pull libreoffice/online`.

BUT : when i use this command,

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for libreoffice/online:latest not found
```

I search on the web if someone had the same problem but i found nothing at all.

Sorry if i wrote something bad i'm still learning linux.

Could someone help me please ?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> #### Pull an image from Docker Hub
>
> To download a particular image, or set of images (i.e., a repository), use `docker pull`. If no tag is provided, Docker Engine uses the `:latest` tag as a default.

As you can see at [hub.docker.com/r/libreoffice/online/tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/libreoffice/online/tags) (and also the error message says so), there is no `latest` tag for this image. Try:

```
docker pull libreoffice/online:master
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot -_- they sould've replace `docker pull libreoffice/online` by the command you gave because a noob like be dont know that. Thanks again for the help !

Comment: What do i have to do after downloading this image ? I used `docker run id_image` but after a few seconds, the terminal stop. No error, no message not a freeze. And i dont know what i should do